# Selecting an item from a listview and producing a sound file

Tags: vb.net

I have created a listview that has 2 columns, the first column represents English words and the second column represents French words. When i select a row and press a button i want to produce a sound that represents the word selected. 
I thought I could identify each row and when a button is pressed the correct sound file will be used, Here is my code so far but it is absolute rubbish... I am open to anything really as long as it will work :)

```
    Private Sub ListenBtn_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles ListenBtn.Click
    Dim x As Integer
    x = 0
    If ListView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0 Then
        ListView1.Items(0) = x + 1
        ListView1.Items(1) = x + 2
    End If
    Select Case x
        Case 1 = My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.hello, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        Case 2 = My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.goodbye, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Unclear exactly what you're doing. Does the listview allow multiple selections? Why are you updating the items in listview?

Comment: `x = ListView1.SelectedItems(0).Index`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to approach this, but seeing as how your name is "MassiveNoob", I will try to keep this as simple as possible.

First, Double Click on your button in design view if you are using Visual Studio(which I assume that you are), and in the click event, add the following..

```
  if listview1.selecteditems.count > 0 then

        If listview1.SelectedItems(0).Text = "<Whatever is in column 1 of your row>" Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.hello, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        ElseIf listview1.SelectedItems(0).Text = "<Whatever is in column 2 of your row>" Then
            My.Computer.Audio.Play(My.Resources.goodbye, AudioPlayMode.WaitToComplete)
        End If
  End If
```